# A few simple questions about functions that have no references being greyed out in visual studio 2019?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

[image]

Not everything though

```
Public Shared Async Function getMarketDetailFromAllExchangesAsync() As Task
    Dim taskList = New List(Of Task)
    Dim starttime = jsonHelper.currentTimeStamp
    LogEvents("Start Getting Market Detail of All")
    For Each account In uniqueAccounts().Values
        Dim newtask = account.getMarketInfoAsync().ContinueWith(Sub() account.LogFinishTask(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, starttime))
        taskList.Add(newtask)
        'newtask.ContinueWith(Sub() LogEvents(account.ToString))
    Next
    Await Task.WhenAll(taskList.ToArray)
    Dim b = 1
    'Await getPairsPriceStepForAllAccountsAsync()
End Function

Private Shared Async Function getPairsPriceStepForAllAccountsAsync() As Task

    For Each account In uniqueAccounts()
        Await account.Value.getPairsPriceStepAsync()
    Next

End Function
```

getPairsPriceStepForAllAccountsAsync is greyed out. I know it's because it has no reference and can be deleted safely. However, the function getMarketDetailFromAllExchangesAsync also have 0 references and it's black.

I wonder why?

Both can be commented out safely.

I wonder if I can easily found such functions too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because one is `Private` and one is `Public`. A `Private` method not called within the same class is guaranteed not to be called anywhere, while a `Public` method could be called in some other non-accessible code.

Comment: That is precisely the issue. Wow.